# bash scriptでターミナルに結果を表示せず、ファイルにのみ出力する方法は？

Tags: bash

jsonファイルだけを出力する方法を教えてください。

```
echo -e "$STR" | tee $date.json
```

ここのechoをなんとかすればできるんじゃないかとおもってはいます。
でもまだ初心者なので具体的にどんなコマンドを使ったらいいのかわからないのでぜひ教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

`tee` コマンドが「標準出力とファイルの両方」に出力するコマンドなので、単に `>` を使ってリダイレクトすればよさそうです。

```
echo -e "$STR" > $date.json
```